# How to receive paypal send money ipn

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

i would wish to get some clarification about paypal send money transaction.If someone sends money to my paypal account,will paypal notify me of that transaction in my Ipn Handler?Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You will receive the notification in your IPN listener if someone sends money to your PayPal account.

Noted : If you send money to an unconfirmed account, PayPal will not send an IPN message.